# how i can treat with folders can't delete on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

on my home there are some folders and there is a lock on each one and when i try to delete them show me massage say

Error removing file /home/ahmed/8/f7107674.txt: Permission denied

how i can delete it?

Comment: Can you run `ls -ld /home/ahmed/8` and post the output? You'll likely have to run `sudo chown ahmed /home/ahmed/8` to delete the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to go from Root.

1. `sudo -s`
   With this command you get a root access
2. `nautilus`
   This can open file manager with root acces to everywhere. This means you can modify,delete,create.
   There you go.